# JPA persist entity with refreshing nested entity strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm questioning myself to how could I perform that following scenario:

Let's take a sample entity `Item`

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Entity
class Item implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "item_category", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Category> categories;

    @PrePersist
    protected void generateUuid() {
        id = UUID_GENERATOR.generate();
    }
}
```

and `Category`

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Entity
class Category implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @PrePersist
    protected void generateUuid() {
        id = UUID_GENERATOR.generate();
    }
}
```

In my use case, `Item` should have many `Category` but `Item` can't directly create or update `Category`, it must use existing `Category` (image a drop down list of categories managed by administrator). That why `Cascade.PERSIST` and `Cascade.MERGE` are missing.

Now imagine following API `POST /api/items` with such JSON request structure

```
{
    "name": "new item",
    "categories": [
        "6d126e36-a7a5-11e7-abc4-cec278b6b50a",
        "88d5a052-a7a5-11e7-abc4-cec278b6b50a"
    ]
}
```

That should create a **new items** with existing `Category` with given *ids* (consider that ids are correct and exist).

However I would return response that contain complet nested entity values:

```
{
    "name": "new item",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "6d126e36-a7a5-11e7-abc4-cec278b6b50a",
            "name": "CAT_A"
        },
        {
            "id": "88d5a052-a7a5-11e7-abc4-cec278b6b50a",
            "name": "CAT_B"
        }
    ]
}
```

To avoid boilerplate, imagine that `Dto` and `DtoToEntityMapper` (and reverse) are present and working as expected.

The problem is when I will `persist()` new `Item` entity produces from JSON:

```
Item(
  id=null,
  name="new item",
  Categories:[
    Category(
      id="6d126e36-a7a5-11e7-abc4-cec278b6b50a",
      name=null
    ),
    Category(
      id="6d126e36-a7a5-11e7-abc4-cec278b6b50a",
      name=null
    )
  ]
)
```

Every below instance are **detached**.

**Problem** is after `persist()` every `Category` instance seems to be detached (or at least `name` is still equals to `null`).

So what's the best way to retrieve `Category` fields?

1. Should I use `refresh(item)` after `persist(item)`?
2. Should I use **attached** `Category` instead of **detached** and thus fetching each `Category` using `id` before `persist(item)`?
3. May I use same representation for *request* (`POST` request body) and *response*, thus name will be pre-filled. But what's happen if `id` is correct but `name` is not (since I don't accept `Category` update from `Item`)? Simply ignore `name` or raise exception?
4. Other way

In addition if 2. is best solution, where should I fetch those nested entities? I mean in `Controller` (*presentation layer*), in `DtoToEntityMapper` (*presentation layer*), in `Service` (*service layer*)

---

PS: Please I would stick to `JPA` specification and not using `Hibernate` specific features.
PS2: I would be able to do in single `POST` request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `entityManager.merge()` instead of `entityManager.persist()` should do the trick. It will return the managed instance so accessing its categories should give you the categories including the description.

Note: Be sure that you use the managed instance after the call.